# Conditional expectation of an integral depending of a Brownian Motion

Tags: probability, brownian-motion, conditional-expectation

*Hello there.* I would like to find $$\mathbb{E} [B_1 | \int_0^2 B_s ds ] $$ where $(B_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is a standard Brownian motion.

I tried the following but I'm pretty sure this is utterly false :

"***If***  $(B_1,\int_0^2 B_s ds)$ is a Gaussian vector, we would have
$$   \mathbb{E} [B_1 | \int_0^2 B_s ds ] = a \int_0^2 B_s ds$$ for some $a\in \mathbb{R}$.
It follow that $$\frac{3}{2} = \mathbb{E}[B_1\int_0^2 B_s ds] = \mathbb{E} [(\int_0^2 B_s ds) \mathbb{E} [B_1 | \int_0^2 B_s ds ]] = a \mathbb{E}[\int_0^2 B_s ds] = a\frac{4}{3} $$
And I would conclude that $a=\frac{9}{8}$."

Problem is $(B_1,\int_0^2 B_s ds)$ is probably not a Gaussian vector... so any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(B_1,\int_0^{2} B_s ds)$ is indeed jointly Gaussian and this implies that the conditional expectation is just a  constant $c$  times $\int_0^{2} B_s ds$. The constant can be evaluted using $E[B_1\int_0^{2} B_s ds]=E[\int_0^{2} B_s ds)]^{2}$. Can you do this (simple) evaluation? [LHS is $\int_0^{2} EB_1B_s ds$].

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Just a question : how do you know the vector is jointly Gaussian ?

Comment: Use the fact that the integral here is a Riemann integral. Write it as the limit of Riemann sums and recall that the finite dimensional distributions of $(B_t)$ are all Gaussian.  @Parchment2382

Comment: Thank you. So both coordinate are Gaussians but as they’re not independents shouldn’t we use something else to prove they are jointly Gaussian ? Linearity maybe ?     
The definition I use for jointly Gaussian imply $aB_1 +b\int_0^2 B_s ds$ should be a Gaussian for all $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$. I don’t know how to do that as there aren’t independents.

Comment: All linear combinations of jointly Gaussian r.v.'are Gaussian and this extends to vectors too. Independence is not required here.   @Parchment2382

Comment: Ok. Thanks again.